# Окрашивание активной строки в цвет

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется функция которая окрашивает нажатую (активную) строку в голубой цвет, путем добавления строке класса `blue_row`. Нужно доработать функцию, чтобы в таблице была только одна активная строка. Класс `row_summary` по умолчанию для всех строк. Я `js` только начал изучал, поэтому буду благодарен за развернутые ответы.

```
function initTableRows() {
    $("body").on("click","tr.row_summary", function() {
        var $trr = $(this);
        $trr.toggleClass('blue_row');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто перед тем как навесить класс на новую ссылку, удалите его со старой

```
function initTableRows() {
    $("body").on("click", "tr.row_summary", function() {
        var currentActiveLink = $("tr.row_summary.blue_row");
        currentActiveLink.removeClass("blue_row");
        /*
            Нужно добавить проверку, что мы хотим просто
            снять класс с активной ссылки
        */
        if(currentActiveLink[0] == this) return;
        var $trr = $(this);
        $trr.toggleClass('blue_row');
    });
}
```

Для лучшей производительности, можно кешировать новую ссылку в какую-то переменную во вне, и уже обращаться к ней при удалении класса

**UPD**
Если хотите убрать возможность снятия класса с **уже активной** ссылки, то просто закомментируйте проверку условия

Comment: э... ваш первый пример работал, а сейчас чушь какая-то написана.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в первом варианте, если мы нажимали на активную ссылку, то класс все равно бы добавлялся

Comment: зато сейчас при повторном нажатии он пропадает совсем. Привет от пользователей с дребезжащей мышкой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это поведение было и у автора, так как `toggleClass` удаляет класс, если он уже есть

Comment: Но почему вы решили, что именно такое поведение и требуется?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это более логично, чем предположить, что автор использует `toggleClass` по ошибке, да и вопрос заключается в другом

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все верно!